# Position at the same time a div at the bottom and center of a page

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to position a `<div>` at the same time at the bottom and center. I have already tried for hours many combinations of CSS attributes: margin, top/bottom, margin-top/bottom, absolute/relative/fixed, etc.

As far as I understand since the outer container is position relative:

```
header {
    position: relative;
    min-height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #c9c9c9;
    background-image: url('shiny-wallpaper-black.jpg');
    background-position: center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}
```

Then my `<div>`:

```
<div style="position: absolute; bottom: 8%; left: 0%; !important">
    <div align = Center style=""> Partner with: </div>
    <a href="http://www.harveymilton.com">
        <img src="assets/harveymilton.png"  style="width:50%;height:50%">
    </a>    
</div>
```

If I put `position: absolute` then I get the `<div>` at the bottom but not centered. If I change `position: relative` then the `<div>` is centered but not at the bottom. How can I get both?

Comment: can you send a picture illustrating what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple way is to set a div with magin:auto inside the absolute div

```css
body>div {
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
left:0;
width:100%;
}

div div {
display:table;/* or widthh:xx;*/
margin:auto;
border:solid;
```

```html
<div>
<div>margin:auto + display or width</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this, one option is to use a wrapper element with `display: flex` rule, like this:

```css
.wrapper {
    /* bar at the bottom */
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;

    /* child items will be horizontally centered */
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div>Hello!</div>
</div>
```